# Keyword "const" not working inside datatype struct

Tags: struct, verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to create a structure with some constant data types in it. It's throwing an error when I am trying to compile it. Can't we use `const` inside a `struct`?

```
typedef
 struct {
   const bit        SOF = 1'b0;      //Start-of-frame bit.
         bit [10:0] MSG_ID;     //A unique message ID.
   const bit        ID_XTND = 1'b0;      //1'b0 for base format.
         bit [3:0]  CTRL;       //Data length code = 4.
         bit [15:0] DATA;        //Simplified payload data.
         bit [15:0] CRC;         //Cyclic redundancy check.
   const bit        CRC_EOF = 1'b0;      //CRC-EOF delimiter bit.
   const bit [6:0]  EOF = 7'b1111111;    //End-of-frame field.
         } CAN_FRAME_t;
```

I am getting an error:

> expecting a symbol that could start a datatype

It works if I remove `const`.

Answer (score 2):

No, `const` is a variable declaration modifier, not a type modifier.